# Update CQL Cassandra using Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, cql, kundera

I have a requirement where I need to update a column value for CQL cassandra table. I tried Kundera but seems like it is used for TQL Mode.

Any pointers to use Play for updating CQL cassandra table??

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you the [Datastax cassandra driver](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/whatsNew2.html). You can do an update like:

```
Statement statement = QueryBuilder.update("simplex", "songs")
    .with(set("artist", "Vasili Ostertag"))
    .where(eq("id", UUID.fromString("f6071e72-48ec-4fcb-bf3e-379c8a696488")));

getSession().execute(statement);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Kundera you can run as em.createNativeQuery(). Kundera also supports Datastax's java driver btw. This should help you out
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/blob/273c13342ddd1aceed0cd23504649926ce8fdb84/src/kundera-cassandra/cassandra-core/src/test/java/com/impetus/client/persistence/NativeQueryTest.java